# DLL not working

Tags: c++, dll

Recently, I decided to get into DLL programming with C++.
I made a simple DLL but when I inject it into a process, nothing happens.
Here's the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
if(fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH){
MessageBoxA(0,"Injected","Injected",MB_OK);
}
return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

It's supposed to display a message box when it gets injected into a process, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated

I used a dll injector to inject it into a process. And my OS is windows 7.

Comment: where is the compilation parameters?

Comment: did you try it on a windows 98 or a Windows 8

Comment: how did you think you are able to inject your dll? where is your dll injection/loader code?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, so I won't make this an answer. But I'm pretty sure that attempting to spawn windows in `DllMain` is a bad idea.

Comment: I used a dll injector to inject it into a process. And my OS is windows 7.

Comment: What I want to do is inject this DLL to a process and edit the process's memory. I tried creating a thread but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: To edit another process memory you have to change the flags associated with allocated pages for the process in memory and change it to writeable. Anyway you have to deal with the security descriptors, ACL and other thechnologies, like DEP, antiviruses or UAC, depending of your functions being used under the Windows7 Win32 API.

Comment: Injection is probably a bad place to start with DLL programming, since you're diving into the deep end. You should start with non-injected DLLs first.

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to read these books (from my bookstore), before you can proceed (to understand the basics) :

- [Win32 System Programming. A Windows® 2000 Application Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201703106) by Johnson M. Hart
- [Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572319968) by Jeffrey Richter
- [Writing Secure Code for Windows Vista](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623937) by Michael Howard, David LeBlanc,

That is true, especially the part describing the ASR (adress space randomization), making it viirtually impossible to inject you DLL function into another process (and, rewriting some function call with your own function, either system function calls or public functions in a process) without raising an exception, except you are familiar with very advanced thechniques related with the Windows messaging and elevationg priveleges fot the call being called, bases on a known (or, not really) code flaws in a kernel functions from NT kernel (KERNEL32.dll and relevant libs).

Comment: JR book is one of my favorite, there are some very handful tips out from there